# DFC_PREFERENCE_LOAD_FAILED Failed to load per sistent preferences from null

Tags: java, jar, documentum

I have one documentum application , when i have created a jar of the project through eclipse by  removing reference of config folder from eclipse ,

the jar is executable , in my classpath i have a value of DCTM.jar and config folder , when i was trying to run this jar through batch file ,i was getting following

exceptions

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: dfc.properties
    at com.documentum.fc.common.impl.preferences.PreferencesManager.locateMainPersistentStore(PreferencesManager.java:357)

    at com.documentum.fc.common.impl.preferences.PreferencesManager.readPersistentProperties(PreferencesManager.java:311)

    at com.documentum.fc.common.impl.preferences.PreferencesManager.<init>(PreferencesManager.java:37)

    at com.documentum.fc.common.DfPreferences.initialize(DfPreferences.java:79)

    at com.documentum.fc.common.DfPreferences.getInstance(DfPreferences.java:58)

    at com.documentum.fc.impl.RuntimeContext.<clinit>(RuntimeContext.java:177)

    at com.documentum.fc.client.DfClient.<clinit>(DfClient.java:700)

    at com.documentum.com.DfClientX.getLocalClient(DfClientX.java:43)

    at com.impact.qtl12.documentum.services.DocumentumHandler.setIdfClient(DocumentumHandler.java:123)

    at com.impact.qtl12.documentum.services.DocumentumHandler.getDocumentumHandler(DocumentumHandler.java:154)

    at com.impact.qtl12.imports.UI.CSVFile.QTL.<init>(QTL.java:115)

    at com.impact.qtl12.imports.UI.CSVFile.QTL.main(QTL.java:599)

1422 [main] WARN com.documentum.fc.client.security.internal.RegistrationMgr  - [DFC_SECURITY_GR_PUBLICATION_FAILED] Publication

of DFC instance with global registry failed

DfException:: THREAD: main; MSG: [DFC_BOF_GLOBAL_REGISTRY_NOT_CONFIGURED] A global registry is not configured; ERRORCODE: ff; NE

XT: null

    at com.documentum.fc.client.security.impl.DfcIdentityPublisher.<init>(DfcIdentityPublisher.java:51)

    at com.documentum.fc.client.security.internal.RegistrationMgr.register(RegistrationMgr.java:34)

    at com.documentum.fc.impl.RuntimeContext.<clinit>(RuntimeContext.java:191)

    at com.documentum.fc.client.DfClient.<clinit>(DfClient.java:700)

    at com.documentum.com.DfClientX.getLocalClient(DfClientX.java:43)

    at com.impact.qtl12.documentum.services.DocumentumHandler.setIdfClient(DocumentumHandler.java:123)

    at com.impact.qtl12.documentum.services.DocumentumHandler.getDocumentumHandler(DocumentumHandler.java:154)

    at com.impact.qtl12.imports.UI.CSVFile.QTL.<init>(QTL.java:115)

    at com.impact.qtl12.imports.UI.CSVFile.QTL.main(QTL.java:599)


15:04:10,222 ERROR [main] Application - DfException Exception occurred while executing method getDocbaseList of DocumentumHandle

r class

15:04:10,222 ERROR [main] Application - [DM_DOCBROKER_E_NO_DOCBROKERS]error:  "No DocBrokers are configured"

15:04:11,879 ERROR [main] Application - QTLConnectionException Exception occurred while executing method populateAvailableDocBas

eCombo of CSVImport class

15:04:11,879 ERROR [main] Application - [DM_DOCBROKER_E_NO_DOCBROKERS]error:  "No DocBrokers are configured"

[DM_DOCBROKER_E_NO_DOCBROKERS]error:  "No DocBrokers are configured"
    at com.impact.qtl12.documentum.services.DocumentumHandler.getDocbaseList(DocumentumHandler.java:190)

    at com.impact.qtl12.imports.UI.CSVFile.QTL.populateAvailableDocBaseCombo(QTL.java:627)

    at com.impact.qtl12.imports.UI.CSVFile.QTL.addTargetGroup(QTL.java:264)

    at com.impact.qtl12.imports.UI.CSVFile.QTL.createShell(QTL.java:565)

    at com.impact.qtl12.imports.UI.CSVFile.QTL.launch(QTL.java:587)

    at com.impact.qtl12.imports.UI.CSVFile.QTL.main(QTL.java:607)
```

But when i was trying to run the same application by specifying the address compiled main class with library folder in the same directory

the application was launched , so what is the difference between these two cases

Answer (score 0):

The EMC Documentum DFC needs dfc.properties to find the avialable documentum docbrokers. The dfc.properties files should be on your classpath.
The exact lookup mechanism of this file is dependent of what version of DFC you are using. But placing this file on your classpath should work with all versions.

Comment: i was setting the dfc.properties  in classpath but the application was not getting it , it was throwing same exception of dfc.properties not found exception , i was setting classpath with following commands   this is the command i am using for setting classpath

set classpath=%CLASSPATH%;D:\documentum\config

and for executing the jar file command is

java -jar "D:\Version Test\QTL.jar"   , also from where i was launching the application it was creating folder named as "documentum" , so where it was getting the reference of documentum

Comment: which DFC version are you using?